# ¿Cómo puedo dar acceso a apache a un dispositivo externo en Linux?

Tags: linux, apache2

Estoy realizando un proyecto de acceso via web a todos los dispositivos conectados a mi Raspberry Pi 3+ por lo que levanté un servidor web en Raspian accesible desde todos los dispositivos conectados a mi red. Luego creé una aplicación web para acceder a todos los archivos que hubiera en los dispositivos conectados a la Raspberry. El programa está en PHP pero no tiene problemas para recorrer todas las rutas absolutas que le paso. El problema es a la hora de visualizar dichos archivos. En los USBs hay de todo: libros, videos, audios, etc. El programa los identifica y los pone a disposición de los usuarios.

Para poder hacer eso, creé un Alias en Apache que apuntara a las diferentes direcciones absolutas en *etc/apache2/mods-available/alias.conf*:

```
Alias 'nombre_alias' /direccion/absoluta/al/dispositivo/usb

<Directory '/direccion/absoluta/al/dispositivo/usb'>
     Options FollowSymlinks
     AllowOverrride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Cuando accedo desde el navegador a `localhost/nombre_alias/Video/Pelicula.avi` me devuelve el siguiente error:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access this resource.

Los tipos de particiones son principalmente NTFS y no, no quiero modificar ni crear ni borrar nada desde los dispositivos. Solo leer. Al observar los permisos veo que todos son 777 (archivos y directorios) con lo que la confusión es aún mayor ¿Alguien puede iluminar mi error? Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿podrías incluir el archivo de configuración del sitio?

Comment: Hola @caprilo Gracias de antemano. Si te refieres al archivo de configuración de algún CMS pues no tiene. Está hecho desde cero. Solo tiene un pequeño .htaccess para hacer urls amigables. Si te refieres que site esta enables con a2ensite, pues solo tengo uno que va a /var/www/html/public. Curiosamente esta carpeta tiene con usuario a mí y como grupo a www-data. Por otra parte, /etc/fstab la unidad USB externa esta montada como ntfs auto,users,permissions 0 0